# Convert images to 3d green magenta glasses

Tags: 3d

I have some mikly way high resolution images. Is there a way to convert them so i can add some 3d effects to be viewable with green/magenta glasses?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert to 3D unless you have (or can generate) some depth data.

Comment: can this be done manually? Something like setting depth on various parts of the image?

Comment: If it was just stars you could treat it like a height map, as in lighter is nearer. But I guess its planets and stuff too?